factor analysis, eigenvalues vs. squared factor loadings vs. scree plot eigenvalues
I performed an exploratory factor analysis for a data set with 8 variables. KMO and Bartlett's  test I also carried out to make sure the data are eligible for this examination.
Scree plot I prepared and I did the factor analysis for different number of factors from 1 to 9 with 2 different rotations: varimax and oblimin. So far so good.
Elbow method suggested 2 factors, eigenvalues on the scree plot were higher than 1 only for 1 factor. The variance of the factors captured from the whole data set reached its maximum in the case of 5 factors and the Chi-square goodness of fit tests lost their significance from factors higher than 3.
I copied the output of the fa() call for 5 factors with the varimax rotation (psych package):
Factor Analysis using method =  minres
Call: fa(r = df_sq1sq9, nfactors = 5, rotate = "varimax")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
      MR1  MR3   MR2   MR5   MR4   h2    u2 com
SQ1  0.13 0.37  0.01 -0.01  0.42 0.33 0.665 2.2
SQ2  0.16 0.07 -0.06  0.09  0.66 0.48 0.517 1.2
SQ3  0.33 0.88  0.01  0.04  0.21 0.94 0.063 1.4
SQ4  0.43 0.10  0.16  0.82  0.11 0.89 0.106 1.7
SQ5  0.85 0.16 -0.06  0.17  0.28 0.86 0.141 1.4
SQ6  0.85 0.34  0.02  0.25  0.16 0.92 0.079 1.6
SQ7  0.34 0.53  0.25  0.30  0.04 0.55 0.450 2.9
SQ8 -0.04 0.08  0.98  0.12 -0.07 1.00 0.005 1.1
SQ9  0.75 0.30  0.00  0.21  0.13 0.70 0.296 1.5

                       MR1  MR3  MR2  MR5  MR4
SS loadings           2.44 1.45 1.06 0.91 0.81
Proportion Var        0.27 0.16 0.12 0.10 0.09
Cumulative Var        0.27 0.43 0.55 0.65 0.74
Proportion Explained  0.37 0.22 0.16 0.14 0.12
Cumulative Proportion 0.37 0.58 0.74 0.88 1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.7
Test of the hypothesis that 5 factors are sufficient.

df null model =  36  with the objective function =  4.83 with Chi Square =  290.78
df of  the model are 1  and the objective function was  0 

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.01 

The harmonic n.obs is  65 with the empirical chi square  0.02  with prob <  0.89 
The total n.obs was  65  with Likelihood Chi Square =  0.15  with prob <  0.69 


The result of the fa() call also contains a list fa_results[["e.values"]]
with the values:
fa_results[["e.values"]]
4.2142109 1.3128191 1.0559469 0.8085356 0.5378116 0.4403557 0.2829727 0.2444338 0.1029137

Question 1: Why does the sum of the squared loadings differ from the eigenvalues? It is important to understand because if I compute the variance that can be captured by the factors, then in the one case I get 74% (SS Loadings), and 88% based on the eigenvalues in the list.
Answer: (1) PCA attributes the whole variance to the principal components identified, whereas factor analysis assumes that the variance is partitioned to shared variance (variance explained by the factors) and unique variance (that cannot be explained by the factors); (2) due to the rotation they also differ. See the easy to read clear explanation: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/seminars/efa-spss/ Or the answer on the link ttnphns posted: What's the relationship between initial eigenvalues and sums of squared loadings in factor analysis?
Question 2: The eigenvalues on the scree plot (parallel analysis) differ from the eigenvalues in fa_results[["e.values"]]  and they do differ from the ss factor loading, too. Why? this is not explained on the link posted.
Thanks for each response!

Thanks for the quick response! My question is similar. The point is how can I compute the variance explained by the factors? Is it then the squared sums of the loadings and eigenvalues can only be interpreted in the sense if there is no rotation?

If the factors are orthogonal, the variance explained by each factor is its sum of squared loadings.

Thanks! What kind of  eigenvalues the scree plot of the fa.parallel(df, fa="fa") shows, as they differ from the e.values variable and the ss loadings?
I will update the question with your answers or you can also add an answer with the link you posted and I will mark your response as an answer.
